# JPanels not added to JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

For my homework extra credit I am creating a JTabbedPane and adding two Jpanels. I feel like I am very close, but it still does not compile. When I run it, both JPanels open, but the JTabbedPane does not. I get a lot of Unknown Source errors. I suspect that at this point my issue in in the JPanels themselves because they started out being JFrames and I have tried (unsuccessfully I think) to convert the JFrames to JPanels.

JTabbedPaneAssignment is supposed to create the JTabbedPane and populate the two panes with the apps DayGui on one tab and OfficeAreaCalculator on the other. I only include the JTabbedPaneAssignment and DayGui classes here. I apologize if its too much code, I have trimmed off a lot of what I consider extraneous, but there may still be too much.

Here is the calling class JTabbedPaneAssignment

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JTabbedPaneAssignment extends JPanel
{
    public JTabbedPaneAssignment()
    {
        //super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        DayGui pnlDay = new DayGui();
        OfficeAreaCalculator  pnlOffice = new OfficeAreaCalculator ();
        this.add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.add(panel1,"First panel");
        tabbedPane.add(panel2,"Second panel");


        //JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Pane #1");
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        tabbedPane.addTab("DayGui", panel1);
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

        //JComponent panel2 = makeTextPanel("Pane #2");
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(410, 50));
        tabbedPane.addTab("OfficeAreaCalculator", panel2);
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);
        add(tabbedPane);
    }

    protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text)
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }

    // Create JTabbedPane
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTabbedPane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTabbedPaneAssignment(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JTabbedPane DayGui = new JTabbedPane();
        JTabbedPane OfficeAreaCalculator = new JTabbedPane();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is DayGui class. It started out as a JFrame, but I am trying to convert it to a JPanel. I think my issue is in this section of code, but I don't know

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

//public class DayGui extends JPanel
public class DayGui extends JPanel
{
    private JPanel dayPanel;
    private JButton cmdGood;
    private JButton cmdBad;

    public DayGui()
    {
        //dayPanel = new JPanel("Messages");

        cmdGood = new JButton("Good");
        cmdBad = new JButton("Bad");

        Container c = dayPanel.getRootPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        c.add(cmdGood);
        c.add(cmdBad);

        dayPanel.setSize(300, 150);

        ButtonsHandler bhandler = new ButtonsHandler();
        cmdGood.addActionListener(bhandler);
        cmdBad.addActionListener(bhandler);

        dayPanel.setVisible(true);
        dayPanel.getRootPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    }

    class ButtonsHandler implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getSource() == cmdGood)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Today is a good day!",
                        "Event Handler Message",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            if (e.getSource() == cmdBad)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Today is a bad day!",
                        "Event Handler Message",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here goes a second time. Now you've got the `DayGui` class up, we notice that you're trying to use `dayPanel` before you've initialised it. i.e. nowhere do you say `dayPanel = new JPanel();`. This resulted in a `NullPointerException` being thrown in your code, screwing up your normal course of exection. Fix this and your `DayGui` class would run fine at runtime.

Among your codebase, you also do some very funky things, namely start using something but never getting around to finishing it up. An example of this is you extending `JPanel`, but resorting to using a member variable of type `JPanel` to do the rest of the work. The suggestion is to scrap the instance variable all together and use the methods you've inherited from extending `JPanel`.

Now lets move onto your `JTabbedPaneAssignment` class. Although not terrible, the code is not very readable and it repeats itself in many places (adding your tabbedpanel multiple times). If you were to take this code further into a larger project, maintenance and debugging would quickly become a problem.

For the purposes of showing you how much clutter you had in your code, I've quickly rewritten your provided code to be compilable, and should roughly do what you're working on.

#### `JTabbedPaneAssignment`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;



public class JTabbedPaneAssignment extends JPanel
{
    public JTabbedPaneAssignment()
    {
        final JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        final DayPanel dayPanel = new DayPanel();
        final JPanel officePanel = new JPanel();

        tabbedPane.add("DayGui", dayPanel);
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

        tabbedPane.add("OfficeAreaCalculator", officePanel);
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(1, KeyEvent.VK_2);

        add(tabbedPane);
    }



    // Create JTabbedPane
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTabbedPane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JTabbedPaneAssignment(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### `DayGui - renamed as DayPanel`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DayPanel extends JPanel {

    public DayPanel() {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        final JButton goodButton = new JButton("Good");
        final JButton badButton = new JButton("Bad");

        ActionListener listener = new DayPanel.ButtonsHandler();
        goodButton.addActionListener(listener);
        badButton.addActionListener(listener);

        add(goodButton);
        add(badButton);
    }

    class ButtonsHandler implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            final String command = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getActionCommand();

            if (command.equals("Good")) {
                showMessage("Today is a good day!");
            } else if (command.equals("Bad")) {
                showMessage("Today is a bad day!");
            }
        }

        // Show popup message
        private void showMessage(String message) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message,
                    "Event Handler Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

So what is different in these? Basically, I've removed your `NullPointerException` you were getting in `DayGui`. Any other changes I've made are with the intention than you try and keep your code clutter free, so you really know what is going on in your code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I will study this. I know my code is a mess. Its the result of trying 50 different things as my head explodes, like in the movie Scanners ;
)

Answer (score 3):

You have been very ambiguous with your question, and you've posted way more code than anyone here has time to trawl through.

I've made a very small but working `JTabbedPane` example for you to see *the smallest* amount of work you need to get it working.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

public class JTabbedPaneExample extends JFrame{

    public JTabbedPaneExample(String title){
        super(title);
        setSize(800,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        
        JPanel panelOne = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelTwo = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.add(panelOne,"First panel");
        tabbedPane.add(panelTwo,"Second panel");
        
        add(tabbedPane);
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        new JTabbedPaneExample("JTP Example").setVisible(true);
        
    }
}
```

Then running, this code looks like:

[image]

If you repeat the same process in your code, and you've still got errors, then the problem is not with your `JTabbedPane`, but something else.

Comment: I apologize. I'm not sure how much code to include. I do see the JTabbedPane similar to what you display. The issue is that the DayGui & OfficeAreaCalculator do not display IN the tabbed panes. They do pop up outside of the tabbed pane, and they exit successfully when I exit the JTabbedPane

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see anything to suggest your behaviour in the code. Can you define DayGUI etc, and only show the code that is relevant to what you're talking about. We don't know if you're referring to the first class or the second.

Comment: I updated my code above. I don't know if the issue is in the first class, JTabbedPaneAssignment (that creates the JTabbedPane ans is supposed to populate the panes), or if its in the JPane class DayGui. Its seems to me that DayGui is the culprit, especially since I am trying to convert it from a JFrame to a JLabel.

Answer (score 1):

> When I run it, both JPanels open, but the JTabbedPane does not. I get
>   a lot of Unknown Source errors.

Well, based on your code and your import section:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

This lines won't compile (unless `DayGUI` and `OfficeAreaCalculator` classes are in the same package than your `JTabbedPaneAssignment` class):

```
DayGui pnlDay = new DayGui();
OfficeAreaCalculator  pnlOffice = new OfficeAreaCalculator ();
```

This is the only error I've got trying to compile and run your example. I changed lines below:

```
tabbedPane.addTab( "DayGui", new JPanel());
tabbedPane.addTab("Office Calculator", new JPanel());
```

And it worked like a charm.

**Update**

Based on your recent edit (adding your `DayGui` class, thank you) you have couple of mistakes in your code.

***DayGui*** : this class extends of `JPanel` so you need to add your components directly on this class, you don't need this panel:

```
private JPanel dayPanel;
```

You need to set the layout manager, buttons and background directly on `DayGui`class, like this:

```
public DayGui() {
    cmdGood = new JButton("Good");
    cmdBad = new JButton("Bad");

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(cmdGood);
    add(cmdBad);

    setSize(300, 150);

    ButtonsHandler bhandler = new ButtonsHandler();
    cmdGood.addActionListener(bhandler);
    cmdBad.addActionListener(bhandler);
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
}
```

***JTabbedPaneAssignment*** : I think you're trying to add `panel1` and `panel2` as tabs but you use `add` method instead `addTab`:

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
tabbedPane.add(panel1,"First panel");
tabbedPane.add(panel2,"Second panel");
```

Also this line:

```
tabbedPane.addTab("DayGui", panel1);
```

Should be:

```
tabbedPane.addTab("DayGui", pnlDay);
```

Finally in this line you are adding `panel2` for a second time and that's not correct:

```
tabbedPane.addTab("OfficeAreaCalculator", panel2); //I'd comment this line
```

If you make suggested changes you'll see something like this (BTW the CYAN color almost made me blind :P):

[image]

Hope this be helpful and sorry for the extension.